# Multivariate analogue of triple product rule

Tags: thermodynamics, differentiation, calculus

I was doing some thermodynamic calculations and I found the need for a multivariable analogue of the [triple product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule). Basically I had a set of $m$ functions $z_i(y, x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m)$, and I needed to calculate partial derivatives of changes in $x$ resulting from a change in $y$ where all $z_i$ values are simultaneously held constant, i.e., I want to calculate:

$$ \left(\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial y}\right)_{z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m}, \ldots, \left(\frac{\partial x_m}{\partial y}\right)_{z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m} . $$

As a reminder, the regular triple product rule would tell us the following, which unfortunately is not helpful in the multivariable case:

$$ \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_{z} = - \frac{\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)_{x}}{\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_{y}} \qquad \qquad \text{when $m=1$}. $$

To compactify, let's use linear algebra notation and write our problem as us knowing $\mathbf z (y, \mathbf x)$, and wanting to find:

$$ \left(\frac{\partial \mathbf x}{\partial y}\right)_{\mathbf z} = ~ ??? $$

I believe I have the answer to this (which I will post as an Answer), but I am unsure as I cannot find it in standard places. This raises a follow-up question for me, which is whether this has a name?

---

#### Example

I came across the need for the above rule when trying to work out heat capacity in the [grand canonical ensemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_canonical_ensemble), in the case of a multi-component system (multiple chemical potentials $\mu_1, \ldots, \mu_m$ and multiple particle counts $N_1, \ldots, N_m$). In this ensemble our natural variables are temperature $T$ and $\boldsymbol \mu$, but heat capacity is a constant-$\mathbf N$ derivative. We have:

\begin{align}
C_V & = T \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_{V, \mathbf N}
\\
 & = T \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_{V, \boldsymbol \mu} + T { \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial \boldsymbol \mu}\right)_{V, T} }^T \left(\frac{\partial \boldsymbol \mu}{\partial T}\right)_{V, \mathbf N} \qquad \text {(using regular multidimensional chain rule)}
\end{align}

So the question is then how to get $ \left(\frac{\partial \boldsymbol \mu}{\partial T}\right)_{V, \mathbf N} $, i.e., here $\mathbf x = \boldsymbol \mu$ and $\mathbf z = \mathbf N $. Besides grand canonical ensemble, similar examples would appear if we are considering ensembles involving vectorial quantities, such as magnetization or angular momentum.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially we are asking, when $y$ changes, what movement in $\mathbf x$ is needed to ensure that $\mathbf z$ stays constant. We have this exact differential for changes in $\mathbf z$:

$$\mathrm d\mathbf z = \mathbf J \, \mathrm d\mathbf x+ \left(\frac{\partial \mathbf z}{\partial y}\right)_{\mathbf x} \, \mathrm dy  $$

where $\mathbf J$ is a Jacobian-like matrix, with elements given by:

$$ J_{ij} = \left(\frac{\partial z_i}{\partial x_j}\right)_{y,x_1,\ldots,x_n \text{ excluding } x_i}. $$

Now just set $\mathrm d \mathbf z = 0$, and isolate $\mathrm d\mathbf x/\mathrm d y$ to get the answer:

$$ \left(\frac{\partial \mathbf x}{\partial y}\right)_{\mathbf z} = - \mathbf J ^{-1} \left(\frac{\partial \mathbf z}{\partial y}\right)_{\mathbf x}. $$

Alternatively, we might write this as:

$$ \left(\frac{\partial \mathbf x}{\partial y}\right)_{\mathbf z} = - [(\boldsymbol \nabla_{\mathbf x} \mathbf z)_y] ^{-1} \left(\frac{\partial \mathbf z}{\partial y}\right)_{\mathbf x}. $$

---

So for my heat capacity example, we get:

$$
C_V = T \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_{V, \boldsymbol \mu} + T { \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial \boldsymbol \mu}\right)_{V, T} }^T \left[ (\nabla_{\boldsymbol \mu}\mathbf N)_{V, T} \right]^{-1}
\left(\frac{\partial \mathbf N}{\partial T}\right)_{V, \boldsymbol \mu} .
$$

What's interesting is that the matrix $(\nabla_{\boldsymbol \mu}\mathbf N)_{V, T} $ is actually the covariance matrix of particle numbers, multiplied by $kT$. The same matrix also shows up when we try to calculate isothermal compressibility $\beta_T$, where $1/\beta_T = V (\partial p / \partial V)_{T, \boldsymbol N}$ -- here it is slightly less of a surprise since it's know that particle number fluctuations are exactly related to compressibility, but it's interesting that the *inverse* of the covariance matrix (i.e., the precision matrix) is what appears in these calculations.

Comment: What do the subscripts here mean? As in what is the difference between $\left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \right)_x $ and just the usual $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} $. If we assume $z$ is a differentiable function of $x$ and $y$

Comment: This is thermodynamicist's partial derivatives notation, where the subscripts refer to quantities held constant.